# tree diagrams of a question

Tags: syntax-trees

I am having trouble drawing a syntax tree for 3 sentences and I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

The sentences are:

> When did the man find the job?

Comment: This looks like homework. We can't (or won't) assist you unless you demonstrate that you've made efforts to find the answer on your own. What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, but asking for syntax trees is off topic.

Comment: olfa, welcome to Linguistics SE. Syntax trees are on topic on this site, however we have opted for not accepting syntax tree questions unless they show prior effort. Please edit your question to include your take on it: how would you do it for your example?

Comment: okay aacally this is what i did:

Comment: when did the man find a job? when is a wh pronoun and did is anauxiliary and the is a determiner .man is a noun find is a verb . a is a determiner and job is a noun this was the first level.then (a + job-> NP) + find = VP.THEN the np(when)+aux(did)+np(the man)+vp(find a job)=S